# Checking whether an android phone has a particular locale

Tags: android, localization

How can I programmatically check whether a phone has a particular locale?

Comment: `getAvailableLocales()` can be get from `Locale` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch an array of `Locale`s by using [`getAvailableLocales()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29), then iterate through it to see if it's available.

```
boolean hasLocale = false;
String myLocale = "en";
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    if (locale.getLanguage().equals(myLocale)) {
        hasLocale = true;
    }
}
// Value of `hasLocale` is what you want here!
```